# Enviar correo usando mail() de PHP

Tags: php, html, mail

Tengo un formulario muy simple con tres campos y lo que pretendo es enviar un mensaje por correo electrónico usando la función `mail()` de `PHP`.

**Formulario**:

```
<form action="email.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message">Mensaje</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" required></textarea>
    </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Enviar Mensaje</button>
</form>
```

**email.php**:

```
<?php

    $to = 'correo@correo.com';
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $header = "Mensaje enviado desde la web";

    mail($to, $header, $message);
```

Hasta donde he podido probar:

- PHP se ejecuta correctamente, porque usando `phpinfo()` me devuelve información del servidor.
- Usando console.log las variables `$to`, `$name`, etc., se están pasando bien. Es decir, ninguna variable me da error cuando la obtengo usando `$_POST`.
- Cuando se ejecuta, en teoría, no me da error, pero con mis pocos conocimientos en `PHP` no sé dónde puedo tener el error. Pero el correo puedo confirmar que no lo recibo, ni en la bandeja de entrada ni en la de spam, nada de nada.
- Los ficheros, tanto `index.html` y `email.php` están en el mismo directorio, como digo, usando `console.log` puedo acceder al contenido de las variables.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: El servidor de correo lo configuraste debidamente ?? En teoria deberia funcionar... no tienes ningun error en ningun lado ?? logs de php, consola, etc ?

Comment: No he configurado nada del servidor, ¿podría venir el problema de ahí?

Comment: Si pero de todos modos, deberia aparecer un error en algun lado. Revisaste los logs de apache y php?

Comment: ¿En qué sistema operativo corre el php?

Comment: PHP lo tengo configurado en el host de banahosting